# Drawing a rubberband on a panel without redrawing everything in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I use a wx.PaintDC() to draw shapes on a panel. After drawing the shapes, when I left click and drag mouse, a rubberband (transparent rectangle) is drawn over shapes. While dragging the mouse, for each motion of mouse, an EVT_PAINT is sent and everything (all shapes and rectangle) is redrawn.

How do I just draw the rubberband over the existing shapes (I don't want to redraw the shapes), I mean, it would be nice if I can save the existing shapes on some DC object and just draw the rubberband on it. So that the application will draw it faster.

Comment: This question has a [twin at Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/EYtxDuLBSPc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You presumably want to have a look at [`wx.Overlay`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Overlay.html?highlight=overlay). Look [here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/sandbox/test_Overlay.py) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, it helped.